# Java CDI: Decorator with multiple generic params

Tags: java, generics, cdi, decorator

I have the following structure:

```
@Decorator
public abstract class MyDecorator<T extends BaseEntity, Q extends QueryParams> implements EntityService<T, Q> {

    @Any
    @Inject
    @Delegate
    EntityService<T, Q> delegate;

    @Override
    public T save(T entity) { ... }

}
```

This is the `EntityService` interface declaration:

```
public interface EntityService<T extends BaseEntity, Q extends QueryParams> {

    T save(T entity);

    void deleteById(Integer id);

    void deleteAllById(List<Integer> ids);

    void delete(T entity);

    void deleteAll(List<T> entities);

    T findById(Integer id);

    QueryResultWrapper<T> query(Q parameters);

    Long count(Q parameters);

}
```

Unfortunately, the decorator save method never get called when it should, although no errors are shown ... The only way I got it working was like this:

```
@Decorator
public abstract class MyDecorator<T extends BaseEntity> implements EntityService<T> { ... }
```

Without the `Q extends QueryParams` generic param.

The `MyDecorator` is declared inside `beans.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="all" version="1.1">

    <decorators>
        <class>fortuna.backend.comum.decorators.MyDecorator</class>
    </decorators>

</beans>
```

Any clues?

Comment: You might need to provide even more info. I tried to make a quick snippet with the above and it simply worked for me (using Weld which I presume you use as well). Also in your question you speak of `EntityService` yet you show a code snippet with `CrudService`. Is that a typo or is there another generic class in between?

Comment: A typo, sorry, just fixed. Anyway, what kind of extra info can I provide?

Comment: Could you provide your beans.xml file?

Comment: @hya sorry for taking so long, I've just added

Comment: Can you share any class which implements QueryParams?

Comment: sure, editing right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue. My problem was that I was using `QueryParams` directly in most of the endpoints/services implementations, for instance:

`public class PersonService extends EntityService<Person, QueryParams> { ... }`

In fact, `QueryParams` don't actually `extends QueryParams`, it is the class itself! That's why the `PersonService` wasn't triggering `MyDecorator` at all!

Being so I created an interface called `IQueryParams` and used that instead, like that:

`public abstract class MyDecorator<T extends BaseEntity, Q extends IQueryParams> implements EntityService<T, Q> {`

Now `PersonService` save method does trigger the `MyDecorator`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this ->

```
EntityService<T extends BaseEntity, Q extends QueryParams>
```

If that interface take two Object, one T extends BaseEntity, other Q extends QueryParams, Respectively, you can try directly put the Specific types instead of. Just like this:

To the interface (Here, the most important is to be as generic as posible, so, you pick two names, like A,B, or in your case):

```
public interface EntityService<T, Q> {

T Save(T param);

void otherMethod(Q param);
```

}

To the decorator (Here, at this point, you can choose the types, so is not necesary to be "generic"):

```
public abstract class MyDecorator implements EntityService<BaseEntity, QueryParams>{

@Any
@Inject
@Delegate
EntityService<BaseEntity, QueryParams> delegate;
//If I understood well the problem, this just work and solve your problem, 
//or else... I'm sorry, you can give me more data so I could help you
//a little more

//Check here, I give a concrete type for T abstract generic type, in 
//your case BaseEntity
@Override
public BaseEntity save(BaseEntity entity) { 
    BaseEntity retSomething; //this is ilustrative
    super.save(entity);  //save your entity as you know how.
    return retSomething; //I really don't know why your save method has a 
                         //return statament, but, if you need it, check the 
                         //return type
}

@Override
public void otherMethod(QueryParams param) {
    // Check here, in the interface the name was Q, now here you only
    // can use as param an QueryParams type object

}
```

}

Comment: Hello Damian, first of all thanks a lot for your answer. But now, what about the ´@Delegate´ instance? It need to know the specific type, not just the supertype in order to be injected properly.. @Damian Lattenero

Comment: Ok, I will change my original answer in order to answer this question also.

Comment: And sorry, the answer is Yes, the @Delegate instance MUST know the concrete (is nicer word than specific) type. Let me know if that works

Comment: Damian, the problem there is that the dependency injection will be broken since there would be multiple available beans for that injection point :(

Comment: Mmm... Well, I'm a little lost there... Can you share anything else so I could help you? At least the "typing part" was useful?

Comment: Sure, I think we are almost there, I will update the question today at night with a very closer look to my architecture so u don't feel lost at all. I must leave now but in 3 hours I will have updated the question already. Cheers, and thank you :)

Comment: shared my software architecture with you on bitbucket. Take a look at endpoints, services and repositories mainly, so you can situate yourself

Comment: Sorry I was to bussy, I can't access the repo, I tried to download it or check it online. What IDE are you working with? Eclipse? Intellij? Because with intellij you can configure your beans automatically.

Comment: Yea, Intelij, Anyways I managed to solve the issue, going to write a response now

Comment: Hey! Congrats! Glad to help you

Comment: Yea! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Finally I was able to +1 your answer ajajaj, lack of rep! Bye! Blessings!